# The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) - Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interopservices

I tried to write data to a excel template file using asp.net c#. But I got following exception.

**ExceptionType: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"
Message: "The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"**

Sometimes it works for small count of rows. I cannot find what is the issue.

```
try
{

int rowNumber = 5;  

DataSet ds = ClsSystem.getReviewResponse();     

Excel.Application myExcelApplication = null;
Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook = null ;
Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorkSheet = null;

//copy template
System.IO.File.Copy(excelFilePath, NewExcelFilePath);

myExcelApplication = new Excel.Application(); 
myExcelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false; 

myExcelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook(myExcelApplication.Workbooks._Open(NewExcelFilePath, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)); // open the existing excel file

myExcelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[1]; 
myExcelWorkSheet.Name = "Test sheet";

for (int n = 0; n < ds.Tables.Count; n++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[n].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "A"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["HeaderID"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "B"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["ResponseID"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "C"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["Region"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "D"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["Sector"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "E"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["Facility"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "F"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["Program"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "G"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["AuditDate"].ToString();
            myExcelWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, "H"] = ds.Tables[n].Rows[i]["Auditor1"].ToString();

            rowNumber++;
        }
        rowNumber++;
    }

    try
        {
            myExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(NewExcelFilePath, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
             System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
             System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value); // Save data in excel


            myExcelWorkbook.Close(true, NewExcelFilePath, System.Reflection.Missing.Value); // close the worksheet
            myExcelApplication.Quit();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myExcelWorkSheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkSheet);

            if (myExcelWorkbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkbook);

            if (myExcelApplication != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelApplication);
        }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (myExcelApplication != null)
        {
            myExcelApplication.Quit(); // close the excel application
        }

        throw ex;
    }
```

I want to write more than 500 rows at once.

Comment: You should **always** `ReleaseComObject` your COM objects in right sequence (move `finally` block to outside `try-catch` block). btw, `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is useless.

Comment: I cannot fix the issue moving finally to outside.

Comment: it's not a solution. it's a recomendation. If exception is thrown in first `try-catch` block  (for example: in one of your `for` loops) - your COM objects are not released. Also, if exception is thrown in your second `try-catch` block - you calling `myExcelApplication.Quit()` of already released COM object. So, any exception will break your app.

Comment: oh got it. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Not to rock the boat on your development path entirely, but I find the interop libraries horribly unreliable.  I have had much greater success with ClosedXML.  I write tens of thousands of rows a day and have never had an issue related to ClosedXML.  https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you had no issues with ClosedXML and I agree that COM Interop is a hell, but how exactly this helps with the question? (this should be a comment, not an answer)

Comment: The answer is the suggestion to get off of interop and go to ClosedXML.

Comment: Suggestion is not an answer, right? Suggestion should be a comment. Also, as this answer is still not accepted I think ClosedXML is not an option here. Let me explain more: for example, in some time after now, someone will have same problem. Then someone will google "COMException HRESULT: 0x800706BA site:stackoverflow.com" and found this question with 1 answer. What if someone can't switch to ClosedXML too? Is this answer is still acceptable for him? That's why [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) telling us, that _“don’t do that”_ is not an answer.